# Откуда берется эта странная ошибка при включенной авторизации?

Tags: c#, .net-6, asp.net-core-webapi

При запуске WebApi (net 6) и включенной авторизации (jwt, отключал - пропадала полностью) появляется в консоли ошибка: https://pastebin.com/yw63ZjNr
Пытается использовать метод из Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography, но такая библиотека не установлена там, где регистрируются все зависимости для авторизации и настраивается сама авторизация.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor[43]
      An exception occurred while trying to decrypt the element.
      System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.UnsafeNativeMethods.CryptUnprotectData(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, IntPtr, UInt32, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB ByRef)'.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapiCore(Byte* pbProtectedData, UInt32 cbProtectedData, Byte* pbOptionalEntropy, UInt32 cbOptionalEntropy)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapi(Byte[] protectedSecret)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor.Decrypt(XElement encryptedElement)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[24]
      An exception occurred while processing the key element '<key id="c6b337d8-73f7-4feb-8eda-a9414a7f41a3" version="1" />'.
      System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.UnsafeNativeMethods.CryptUnprotectData(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, IntPtr, UInt32, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB ByRef)'.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapiCore(Byte* pbProtectedData, UInt32 cbProtectedData, Byte* pbOptionalEntropy, UInt32 cbOptionalEntropy)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapi(Byte[] protectedSecret)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor.Decrypt(XElement encryptedElement)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.DecryptElement(XElement element, IActivator activator)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.DeserializeDescriptorFromKeyElement(XElement keyElement)
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.DefaultKeyResolver[12]
      Key {c6b337d8-73f7-4feb-8eda-a9414a7f41a3} is ineligible to be the default key because its CreateEncryptor method failed.
      System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.UnsafeNativeMethods.CryptUnprotectData(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, IntPtr, UInt32, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB ByRef)'.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapiCore(Byte* pbProtectedData, UInt32 cbProtectedData, Byte* pbOptionalEntropy, UInt32 cbOptionalEntropy)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapi(Byte[] protectedSecret)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor.Decrypt(XElement encryptedElement)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.DecryptElement(XElement element, IActivator activator)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.DeserializeDescriptorFromKeyElement(XElement keyElement)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.DeferredKey.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<GetLazyDescriptorDelegate>b__0()
         at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
         at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
         at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
         at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyBase.get_Descriptor()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.CngGcmAuthenticatedEncryptorFactory.CreateEncryptorInstance(IKey key)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyBase.CreateEncryptor()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.DefaultKeyResolver.CanCreateAuthenticatedEncryptor(IKey key)
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.DefaultKeyResolver[12]
      Key {c6b337d8-73f7-4feb-8eda-a9414a7f41a3} is ineligible to be the default key because its CreateEncryptor method failed.
      System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.UnsafeNativeMethods.CryptUnprotectData(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, IntPtr, UInt32, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB ByRef)'.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapiCore(Byte* pbProtectedData, UInt32 cbProtectedData, Byte* pbOptionalEntropy, UInt32 cbOptionalEntropy)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapi(Byte[] protectedSecret)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor.Decrypt(XElement encryptedElement)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.DecryptElement(XElement element, IActivator activator)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.DeserializeDescriptorFromKeyElement(XElement keyElement)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.DeferredKey.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<GetLazyDescriptorDelegate>b__0()
         at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
         at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyBase.get_Descriptor()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.CngGcmAuthenticatedEncryptorFactory.CreateEncryptorInstance(IKey key)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyBase.CreateEncryptor()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.DefaultKeyResolver.CanCreateAuthenticatedEncryptor(IKey key)
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.DefaultKeyResolver[12]
      Key {c6b337d8-73f7-4feb-8eda-a9414a7f41a3} is ineligible to be the default key because its CreateEncryptor method failed.
      System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.UnsafeNativeMethods.CryptUnprotectData(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, IntPtr, UInt32, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB ByRef)'.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapiCore(Byte* pbProtectedData, UInt32 cbProtectedData, Byte* pbOptionalEntropy, UInt32 cbOptionalEntropy)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapi(Byte[] protectedSecret)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor.Decrypt(XElement encryptedElement)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.DecryptElement(XElement element, IActivator activator)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.DeserializeDescriptorFromKeyElement(XElement keyElement)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.DeferredKey.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<GetLazyDescriptorDelegate>b__0()
         at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
         at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyBase.get_Descriptor()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.CngGcmAuthenticatedEncryptorFactory.CreateEncryptorInstance(IKey key)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyBase.CreateEncryptor()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.DefaultKeyResolver.CanCreateAuthenticatedEncryptor(IKey key)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlEncryptor[54]
      An error occurred while encrypting to Windows DPAPI.
      System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.UnsafeNativeMethods.CryptProtectData(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, IntPtr, UInt32, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB ByRef)'.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.ProtectWithDpapiCore(Byte* pbSecret, UInt32 cbSecret, Byte* pbOptionalEntropy, UInt32 cbOptionalEntropy, Boolean fLocalMachine)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.ProtectWithDpapi(ISecret secret, Boolean protectToLocalMachine)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlEncryptor.Encrypt(XElement plaintextElement)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider[48]
      An error occurred while reading the key ring.
      System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.UnsafeNativeMethods.CryptProtectData(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, IntPtr, UInt32, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB ByRef)'.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.ProtectWithDpapiCore(Byte* pbSecret, UInt32 cbSecret, Byte* pbOptionalEntropy, UInt32 cbOptionalEntropy, Boolean fLocalMachine)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.ProtectWithDpapi(ISecret secret, Boolean protectToLocalMachine)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlEncryptor.Encrypt(XElement plaintextElement)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.EncryptIfNecessary(IXmlEncryptor encryptor, XElement element)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.CreateNewKey(Guid keyId, DateTimeOffset creationDate, DateTimeOffset activationDate, DateTimeOffset expirationDate)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.CreateNewKey(DateTimeOffset activationDate, DateTimeOffset expirationDate)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.CreateCacheableKeyRingCore(DateTimeOffset now, IKey keyJustAdded)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.ICacheableKeyRingProvider.GetCacheableKeyRing(DateTimeOffset now)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRingCore(DateTime utcNow, Boolean forceRefresh)
```

Comment: не надо ссылок на текст ошибки, добавьте ошибку в вопрос

Comment: Она там километровая :)

Comment: ну что поделать ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: А какие проблемы с pastebin'ом?)

Comment: Вот если там удалят, или сервис закроется, или еще что, ваш вопрос будет актуален? Через пару лет его возможно будет прочитать и понять? Сомневаюсь... Про поиск еще тоже не забывайте, вот возникнет у другого такая ошибка, пойдет ее гуглить, найдет он ваш вопрос? Не забывайте - SO это база вопросов и ответов, а не форум, где вы общаетесь с комьюнити.

Comment: Ахаха, добавил)

Comment: Цель этого сайта - это создание БД вопросов и ответов. Помошь вам это не цель сайта - это побочный эффект этой цели. Потому, если через Х лет ваша ссылка на pastebin станет неактуальной, то ваш вопрос потеряет какую либо значисмость. Не говоря уже о том, что те, кто будет искать подобные вопросы, не сможет найти ваш, так как у вас здесь нет вашего стектрейса.